# multiple localdb instances in separate files

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, localdb

I'm trying to run the same project multiple times on the same machine, and each instance needs it's own distinct localdb instances stored in it's own personal mdf file (this might sound strange but I have a reason for doing this). Currently I'm attempting to use the same connection string name with different files, but this doesn't work. Here's an example connection string:

```
<add name="dbContext"
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\db-<string-unique-to-project-instance-1>.mdf;Initial Catalog=dbContext;Persist Security Info=True;Trusted_Connection=False;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

However upon running the project the database file is not created as expected, even though interrogation of the connection string that's loaded into memory shows the correct value.

What connection string allows for multiple localdb instances / is there something else I need to do?

Note: I've also tried using a distinct connection string name to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All those databases are created in the same LocalDB instance, which means their names collide.

Let's take the connection string you provided.

All databases are created in the automatic LocalDB instance `v11.0`:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0
```

Each database is created in a separate, uniquely-named file:

```
AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\db-<string-unique-to-project-instance-1>.mdf
```

But all of them are attached to the LocalDB instance under the same database name:

```
Initial Catalog=dbContext
```

The easiest way to fix this is to give each database a unique name, like:

```
Initial Catalog=dbContext-<string-unique-to-project-instance-1>
```

You could also try creating multiple named LocalDB instances, one for each project, but unless you have a good reason to, I'd go with the unique database name in the automatic LocalDB instance.

Comment: Having separate instances allows me to stop/delete these individually. Is there a way to remove each db from the instance and delete the file using a single instance?

Comment: Hey, it's still SQL Server, so DROP DATABASE should do the trick :-)

Comment: True, but from the command line I can run "sqllocaldb.exe stop <instance>" and "sqllocaldb.exe delete <instance>", then remove the file and I'm back to a clean slate. I'm just curious if this would be possible using a single instance, so I'm wondering if there's a way the drop the database using the sqllocaldb.exe util from the command line.

Comment: Or to put it another way, sqllocaldb.exe is already installed and available when I'm using localdb, so stop/delete works with no additional effort. Is there another cmd util that's already installed to drop the database, or would that require another install?

Comment: Why not just use `sqlcmd -Q` to run the query from command line? Like: `sqlcmd -S (localdb)\v11.0 -Q "select @@version"`. I think it's installed with LocalDB, but please double-check that.

Comment: Aha! It looks like they are both installed and ``sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -Q "DROP DATABASE <Initial-Catalog name"`` will drop the database *and* remove the files *if the database is not currently in use*. So now I have two options for managing this. Thank you for your help @KrzysztofKozielczyk!

Comment: No problem. I think you can also use `sp_detach_db` procedure to make sure the database is not in use :-)

Comment: What actually seems to work is dropping connecting users with ``sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -Q "ALTER DATABASE <Initial-Catalog name> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;"``, and then dropping the database.

Comment: Nice. I would probably prefix this commend with `use master;`. In case the database being dropped is the default database for the default account. I bet there's sqlcmd option to set the "active" database too.